# what does the random string classname using Scss in React app means?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, classname

whats the difference between using normal css `ClassName` in react and using node-sass in react?
which is better and how does a scss `ClassName` generates a random string in a browser like `app_contentHeader__xFQea` and what exactly does it mean and why it generates a random string which I hadn't even defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS can be considered as the superset of CSS as it provides many utility functions and syntax that reduce the code length like say

1. & - Reference symbol
2. Partials and @import directive
3. Interpolation and so on

But in the end this scss will be compiled to normal css which browser understands.

And for your next question app_contentHeader__xFQea.

This is a hash code attached to each component css for style encapsulation. So that a style .card will not interfere with .card from another component. This feature doesn't have a dependency on css or scss ie, it will work irrespective of what you use.

If you have worked with angular, there also you can find the same style encapsulation but with something like _ngcontent.